# Raspberry pi won't show pil image

Tags: python, image, raspberry-pi

I got the raspberry pi camera module and followed whatnot show in the example for saving the capture to another PIL in image but the image won't show. When I reference the image in the shell, every thing seems to work fine but displaying it. The code is at 4.3 on http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/latest/recipes1.html (I didn't type the code because I'm writing this on mobile). When typing image into the shell, it returns `<PIL.jpegimageplugin.jpegimagefile image mode=RGB size=1280x720 at 0x1486690>`

After I call image.show nothing displays.

Comment: You need to call `image.show()`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I did and nothing displays. That's my problem

Comment: Please provide the full code.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi the full code is at the link provided under 3.3, then I call image.show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image.show() calls an external viewer program. If you don't have one or are running in a non-graphical environment, it's not going to do anything.

Comment: Duh, I should've known that. Thanks. I will try to find another way to display it like pygame

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, resolved it by installing ImageMagick. In case of Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

Restart your python script after that.

Comment: this exactly does the trick for me! thanks.